# use of gdaltransform in C# code

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

I have a problem to use correctly gdaltransform in a C# project to transform a set of coordinates from a crs to another.

If first try in console command and this line is working good

[image: command line]

my inpufile contains

```
11,4110511566842 -16,3912563064512
11,4672071951958 -15,765159743537
10,9408189433189 -15,7659287774418
10,8827231060401 -16,3901294898696
```

and i get

```
1224514.39872601 -1804722.76625729 0
1224514.39872601 -1689200.13960789 0
1113194.90793273 -1689200.13960789 0
1113194.90793273 -1804722.76625729 0
```

This is the code i tryed

- First Case process.StartInfo.FileName = "gdaltransform.exe"

  ```
  System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

  process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] = fwtoolsPath;
  process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["GDAL_DATA"] = ftwtoolsPath.Replace("bin", "data");
  process.StartInfo.FileName = "gdaltransform.exe";
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:{0} < {1} > D:/Temp/TempCoordinates/coordinates_output.txt", proj, inpuFileName);
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit(processTimeOut);
  ```

In this case the outputfile is not created, no exception catched in code

- Second Case process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"

  ```
  System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

  process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] = fwtoolsPath;
  process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["GDAL_DATA"] =    fwtoolsPath.Replace("bin", "data");
  process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:{0} < {1} > D:/Temp/TempCoordinates/coordinates_output.txt", proj, inpuFileName);
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit(processTimeOut);
  ```

In this case the output file is created but empty, no exception catched in code

Is someone already faced such a problem? do you have an idea about the problem?

I also try to use StandarInput.WriteLine and StandardOutPut.ReadLine() in the process but i didn't succeed. Problem with timeout in StandardOutPut.ReadLine()

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with C# but I must warn you: what you believe to work correctly from the command line does not because you have comma as decimal separator. See the following examples:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857
11,4110511566842 -16,3912563064512
1224514.39872601 -1804722.76625729 0
11.4110511566842 -16.3912563064512
1270272.40417808 -1850077.21040562 0
11 -16
1224514.39872601 -1804722.76625729 0
```

Gdaltranslate is truncating your coordinates at comma and all the decimals are discarded.

BTW. if "fwtoolspath" means that you are still using the good old FWTools binaries you should consider to start using either OSGeo4W or binaries from gisinternals.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and notice to me the problem with comma. you're right too concerning fwtoolspath which is directing ti FWTools binaries. It's historical in this project. Does it coul imply error or problem to maintain the old one?

Comment: If FWTools is OK for your needs then it is not a problem. However, there are huge amount of new features, improvements, and bug fixes done after version `GDAL 1.7.0b2, FWTools 2.4.7, released 2010/01/19` as you can see from the changelog http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/NEWS.